# I want the userId of a person who runs a pipeline which uploads a file into gcp bucket which in turn triggers the CF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, microsoft-teams

I want to drive the person's userid to teams channel who runs a pipeline that uploads a file into gcp bucket. uploading a file into a bucket will automatically trigger the CF in gcp. I can see the CF status in logs but I want to see the person's id who made CF to trigger in the teams channel.My pipeline which uploads file into bucket has only yml files and no underlying .ps or python  file.

I tried using  id_user = $(Build.RequestedForId) in build and release pipeline which deploys storage bucket and CF in gcp but could not achieve as it is throwing error because Build.RequestedForId is not present in my logs.

Can anyone please suggest any solution.

Comment: Do you want to pass the value of the pipeline variable "**`Build.RequestedForId`**" as a parameter into the python script file?

Comment: Do you execute the python script in the pipeline or outside the pipeline?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? Do you want to know WHO has uploaded the file on GCS? With that WHO (the email), you will be able to post something on Teams, correct? And behind the scene, the event to upload the file to GCS will triggered a Cloud Functions to process the file. You want to know in that Cloud Functions the file to process and WHO has uploaded it? Still correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere,  yes..what is said is correct.How can I acheive that. Can you please suggest solution

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that works well but that will require changes in your code.

The solution is to use audit logs to get the logs message as event and to process it.

To achieve that you need:

- Eventarc that use Audit logs on Cloud Storage (don't use native event or Cloud Storage event, you must use the logs!)
- Eventarc will send the message to Cloud Run. So you need to change your Cloud Functions to Cloud Run.

Then you can process your event like that (in python for instance)

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def call_function():
    cloud_event = from_http(request.headers, request.get_data())
    event_data = cloud_event.data

    resource_name = event_data["protoPayload"]["resourceName"]
    eventname = resource_name[resource_name.find("/objects/") + 9 :]
    event_bucket = event_data["resource"]["labels"]["bucket_name"]
    uploader_email = event_data["protoPayload"]["authenticationInfo"]["principalEmail"]
    ... 
    ...
```

With the object, the bucket and the uploader email, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Pipelines have provided the predefined variables to get the ID of user who triggers the pipeline. And these variables will be automatically mapped as the environment variables on the agent machines when running the pipeline jobs.

- [**`Build.RequestedForId`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services): The ID of identity that triggered the current build/run (classic build pipeline/YAML pipeline). The corresponding environment variable is "**`BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID`**".
- [**`Release.RequestedForId`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release): The ID of identity that triggered the current release (classic release pipeline). The corresponding environment variable is "**`RELEASE_REQUESTEDFORID`**".

---

If you want to pass the ID into the Python scrip file (e.g., **`main.py`**) and directly execute the scrip file in the pipeline, you can do like as below:

1. Add below lines in the scrip file.

   - If run in classic build pipeline/YAML pipeline.

     ```py
     # main.py

     import os
     . . .

     user_id = os.environ['BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID']
     print(f'user_id = {user_id}')
     . . .
     ```
   - If run in classic release pipeline.

     ```py
     # main.py

     import os
     . . .

     user_id = os.environ['RELEASE_REQUESTEDFORID']
     print(f'user_id = {user_id}')
     . . .
     ```
2. Then directly execute the Python scrip file in the pipeline.

   ```yaml
   - bash: 'python main.py'
     displayName: 'Run Python script'
   ```

   [image]

---

If you want to pass the ID into the Python scrip file (e.g., main.py) and then execute the updated scrip file outside of the pipeline, you can do like as below:

1. Add below lines in the scrip file.

   - If run in classic build pipeline/YAML pipeline.

     ```py
     # main.py

     . . .

     user_id = '{{Build.RequestedForId}}'
     print(f'user_id = {user_id}')
     . . .
     ```
   - If run in classic release pipeline.

     ```py
     # main.py

     . . .

     user_id = '{{Release.RequestedForId}}'
     print(f'user_id = {user_id}')
     . . .
     ```
2. Then in the pipeline, you can use the pipeline task provided by the extension "[**Replace Tokens**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens&targetId=e798dfe9-efa6-4ece-a142-e9ed554e4ebf&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)" to replace the placeholder token (**`{{Build.RequestedForId}}`** or **`{{Release.RequestedForId}}`**) in the Python script file with the actual value of the corresponding pipeline variable.

   ```yaml
   - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
     displayName: 'Replace tokens in main.py'
     inputs:
       targetFiles: main.py
       tokenPattern: doublebraces
       keepToken: true
   ```

   [image]
3. After successfully running the **`Replace Tokens`** task, the following line in the Python scrip file,

   ```py
   user_id = '{{Build.RequestedForId}}'
   ```

   or

   ```py
   user_id = '{{Release.RequestedForId}}'
   ```

   will be updated to,

   ```py
   user_id = 'xxxxxx'
   ```

   the "**`xxxxxx`**" is the actual value of the user ID who triggered the pipeline. Then you can publish/pass the updated scrip file outside of pipeline to execute.

---

Comment: @srilakshmiponnaganti, Have you checked with the steps shared in my above answer to pass the `Build.RequestedForId` and `Release.RequestedForId` into Python scripts? Is it helpful for you?